# Compute an $n \times n$ determinant

Tags: matrices, determinant

> Compute the following determinant
>
> $$
> \begin{vmatrix}
> a_{1}-b_{1}+x & a_{1}-b_{2}   & \ldots & a_{1}-b_{n}  \\
> a_{2}-b_{1}   & a_{2}-b_{2}+x & \ldots & a_{2}-b_{n}  \\
>      \vdots   & \vdots        & \ddots & \vdots       \\
> a_{n}-b_{1}   & a_{n}-b_{2}   & \ldots & a_{n}-b_{n}+x
> \end{vmatrix}.
> $$

---

I tried for $n=3$ and I used the fact that $\det$ funcion is liniar in each
column.

\begin{align*}
&
\begin{vmatrix}
a_{1}-b_{1}+x & a_{1}-b_{2} & a_{1}-b_{3}\\
a_{2}-b_{1} & a_{2}-b_{2}+x & a_{2}-b_{3}\\
a_{3}-b_{1} & a_{3}-b_{2} & a_{3}-b_{3}+x
\end{vmatrix}
\\
& =
\begin{vmatrix}
a_{1}-b_{1} & a_{1}-b_{2} & a_{1}-b_{3}\\
a_{2}-b_{1} & a_{2}-b_{2}+x & a_{2}-b_{3}\\
a_{3}-b_{1} & a_{3}-b_{2} & a_{3}-b_{3}+x
\end{vmatrix}
+%
\begin{vmatrix}
x & a_{1}-b_{2} & a_{1}-b_{3}\\
a_{2}-b_{1} & a_{2}-b_{2}+x & a_{2}-b_{3}\\
a_{3}-b_{1} & a_{3}-b_{2} & a_{3}-b_{3}+x
\end{vmatrix}
\\
& =%
\begin{vmatrix}
a_{1}-b_{1} & a_{1}-b_{2} & a_{1}-b_{3}\\
a_{2}-b_{1} & a_{2}-b_{2} & a_{2}-b_{3}\\
a_{3}-b_{1} & a_{3}-b_{2} & a_{3}-b_{3}+x
\end{vmatrix}
+%
\begin{vmatrix}
a_{1}-b_{1} & a_{1}-b_{2} & a_{1}-b_{3}\\
a_{2}-b_{1} & x & a_{2}-b_{3}\\
a_{3}-b_{1} & a_{3}-b_{2} & a_{3}-b_{3}+x
\end{vmatrix}
\\
& +%
\begin{vmatrix}
x & a_{1}-b_{2} & a_{1}-b_{3}\\
a_{2}-b_{1} & a_{2}-b_{2} & a_{2}-b_{3}\\
a_{3}-b_{1} & a_{3}-b_{2} & a_{3}-b_{3}+x
\end{vmatrix}
+%
\begin{vmatrix}
x & a_{1}-b_{2} & a_{1}-b_{3}\\
a_{2}-b_{1} & x & a_{2}-b_{3}\\
a_{3}-b_{1} & a_{3}-b_{2} & a_{3}-b_{3}+x
\end{vmatrix}
\\
& =%
\begin{vmatrix}
a_{1}-b_{1} & a_{1}-b_{2} & a_{1}-b_{3}\\
a_{2}-b_{1} & a_{2}-b_{2} & a_{2}-b_{3}\\
a_{3}-b_{1} & a_{3}-b_{2} & a_{3}-b_{3}%
\end{vmatrix}
+%
\begin{vmatrix}
a_{1}-b_{1} & a_{1}-b_{2} & a_{1}-b_{3}\\
a_{2}-b_{1} & a_{2}-b_{2} & a_{2}-b_{3}\\
a_{3}-b_{1} & a_{3}-b_{2} & x
\end{vmatrix}
\\
& +%
\begin{vmatrix}
a_{1}-b_{1} & a_{1}-b_{2} & a_{1}-b_{3}\\
a_{2}-b_{1} & x & a_{2}-b_{3}\\
a_{3}-b_{1} & a_{3}-b_{2} & a_{3}-b_{3}%
\end{vmatrix}
+%
\begin{vmatrix}
a_{1}-b_{1} & a_{1}-b_{2} & a_{1}-b_{3}\\
a_{2}-b_{1} & x & a_{2}-b_{3}\\
a_{3}-b_{1} & a_{3}-b_{2} & x
\end{vmatrix}
\\
& +%
\begin{vmatrix}
x & a_{1}-b_{2} & a_{1}-b_{3}\\
a_{2}-b_{1} & a_{2}-b_{2} & a_{2}-b_{3}\\
a_{3}-b_{1} & a_{3}-b_{2} & a_{3}-b_{3}%
\end{vmatrix}
+%
\begin{vmatrix}
x & a_{1}-b_{2} & a_{1}-b_{3}\\
a_{2}-b_{1} & a_{2}-b_{2} & a_{2}-b_{3}\\
a_{3}-b_{1} & a_{3}-b_{2} & x
\end{vmatrix}
\\
& +%
\begin{vmatrix}
x & a_{1}-b_{2} & a_{1}-b_{3}\\
a_{2}-b_{1} & x & a_{2}-b_{3}\\
a_{3}-b_{1} & a_{3}-b_{2} & a_{3}-b_{3}%
\end{vmatrix}
+%
\begin{vmatrix}
x & a_{1}-b_{2} & a_{1}-b_{3}\\
a_{2}-b_{1} & x & a_{2}-b_{3}\\
a_{3}-b_{1} & a_{3}-b_{2} & x
\end{vmatrix}
\\
& =%
\begin{vmatrix}
a_{1}-b_{1} & a_{1}-b_{2} & a_{1}-b_{3}\\
a_{2}-b_{1} & a_{2}-b_{2} & a_{2}-b_{3}\\
a_{3}-b_{1} & a_{3}-b_{2} & a_{3}-b_{3}%
\end{vmatrix}
+%
\begin{vmatrix}
a_{1}-b_{1} & a_{1}-b_{2} & a_{1}-b_{3}\\
a_{2}-b_{1} & x & a_{2}-b_{3}\\
a_{3}-b_{1} & a_{3}-b_{2} & a_{3}-b_{3}%
\end{vmatrix}
\\
& +%
\begin{vmatrix}
x & 2\left(  a_{1}-b_{2}\right)   & a_{1}-b_{3}\\
a_{2}-b_{1} & a_{2}-b_{2}+x & a_{2}-b_{3}\\
a_{3}-b_{1} & 2\left(  a_{3}-b_{2}\right)   & a_{3}-b_{3}%
\end{vmatrix}
+%
\begin{vmatrix}
x+a_{1}-b_{1} & 2\left(  a_{1}-b_{2}\right)   & a_{1}-b_{3}\\
2\left(  a_{2}-b_{1}\right)   & x+a_{2}-b_{2} & a_{2}-b_{3}\\
2\left(  a_{3}-b_{1}\right)   & 2\left(  a_{3}-b_{2}\right)   & x
\end{vmatrix}
\end{align*}
From here I didn't see any pattern or some manipulations to do in order to compute the determinant. The first determinants after the last $=$ sign is equal to zero after some calculation using Sarrus rule. How can one compute this determinant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This equals $\det (xI+A-B)$ where
$$A=\pmatrix{a_1&a_1&\cdots&a_1\\a_2&a_2&\cdots&a_2\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\a_n&a_n&\cdots&a_n}$$
and
$$B=\pmatrix{b_1&b_2&\cdots&b_n\\b_1&b_2&\cdots&b_n\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\b_1&b_2&\cdots&b_n}.$$
Then $\det(xI+A-B)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $C=B-A$.

But both  $A$ and $B$ have rank $\le 1$, so $C$ has rank $\le 2$. So all
$d\times d$ minors of $C$ vanish for $d\ge3$ and so
$$\det(xI-C)=x^{n}-t_1x^{n-1}+t_2x^{n-2}.$$
Here $t_1$ is the trace of $C$:
$$t_1=\sum_i(b_i-a_i).$$
Also,
$$t_2=\sum_{i<j}\left[(b_i-a_i)(b_j-a_j)-(b_i-a_j)(b_j-a_i)\right].$$

Comment: Could you please briefly comment on how you obtained $t_2$?

Comment: It's just the sum of the $2\times2$ principal minors of $C$.

Answer (score 3):

Given vectors $\rm{a}, \rm{b} \in \mathbb R^n$, where $n \geq 2$, let function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be defined by

$$f (x) := \det \left( x \rm{I}_n + \rm{a} \Bbb{1}_n^\top - \Bbb{1}_n \rm{b}^\top \right)$$

Using the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma),

$$\begin{aligned} f (x) &= \det \left( x \rm{I}_n + \begin{bmatrix} | & | \\ \rm{a} & -\Bbb{1}_n\\  | & | \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} | & | \\ \Bbb{1}_n & \rm{b} \\  | & | \end{bmatrix}^\top \right) \\ &= \det \left( x \rm{I}_2 + \begin{bmatrix} | & | \\ \Bbb{1}_n & \rm{b} \\  | & | \end{bmatrix}^\top \begin{bmatrix} | & | \\ \rm{a} & -\Bbb{1}_n\\  | & | \end{bmatrix} \right) \cdot x^{n-2}\\ &= \det \left( x \rm{I}_2 + \begin{bmatrix} \Bbb{1}_n^\top \rm{a} & -n\\ \rm{a}^\top \rm{b} & -\Bbb{1}_n^\top \rm{b}\end{bmatrix} \right) \cdot x^{n-2}\\ &=\left( x^2 + \mbox{tr} \begin{bmatrix} \Bbb{1}_n^\top \rm{a} & -n\\ \rm{a}^\top \rm{b} & -\Bbb{1}_n^\top \rm{b}\end{bmatrix} x + \det \begin{bmatrix} \Bbb{1}_n^\top \rm{a} & -n\\ \rm{a}^\top \rm{b} & -\Bbb{1}_n^\top \rm{b}\end{bmatrix}\right) \cdot x^{n-2}\\ &= \color{blue}{x^n + \Bbb{1}_n^\top \left(\rm{a} - \rm{b} \right) x^{n-1} + \left( n \, \rm{a}^\top \rm{b} - \Bbb{1}_n^\top \rm{a} \rm{b}^\top \Bbb{1}_n \right) x^{n-2}} \end{aligned}$$